# web scraping if the website by default only shows item 1-50

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the top selling games from steam, but the website only shows 50 items unless I scroll down the webpage. The html code also indicate "showing 1 - 50 of 35728". So how can I get all 35728 results using beautiful soup?

my current request is:

```
request_top_seller = requests.get("https://store.steampowered.com/search/?os=win&filter=globaltopsellers", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
html_topseller = soup(request_top_seller.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: You may be able to get the data from the Steam Labs API (https://dev.streamlabs.com/docs). If not you can try a tool like Selenium (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Selenium can scroll the page for you. I don't think your browser would be able to handle a page that big however (mine can't).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP GET request to the same API your browser makes a request to when visiting that page. I just logged my network traffic to find out its URL and the query string parameters it expects. It doesn't seem to care about request headers. The response from the API is JSON, but unfortunately the key-value pair we are interested in is the `results_html`, which is just a really long HTML string we still need to parse:

```
def main():
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

    url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search/results/"

    params = {
        "query": "",
        "start": "50",
        "count": "50",
        "dynamic_data": "",
        "sort_by": "_ASC",
        "snr": "1_7_7_globaltopsellers_7",
        "filter": "globaltopsellers",
        "os": "win",
        "infinite": "1"
    }

    global response

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()

    html = response.json()["results_html"]

    soup = Soup(html, "html.parser")

    for row in soup.select("a[class*=\"search_result_row\"]"):
        title = row.find("span", {"class": "title"}).text.strip()
        print(title)
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

You can play around with the `start` and `count` key-value pairs in the `params` query string parameter dictionary. Changing these values should give you more- or less items in the response.